# LayerSlider start trigger

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I put one of the Layer Sliders on my page inside a Sliding Bar (drawer). I need to get it to trigger/start playing on the event of the drawer being opened. Right now I think it plays when the page is loaded, which means when they open the drawer, the slideshow starts somewhere in the middle. (And continues playing, so if they close and re-open the drawer it's always at a different place.) How can I get it to start when they click to open the drawer, and always start over when the drawer is opened?

*Edit: Site removed (issue solved)*

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with simulating `click` on slider navigation buttons, when user clicks the toggle button.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.fusion-sb-toggle').click(function(){
    var wasOpenned = $(this).closest('.slidingbar-area').is('.open');
    if(wasOpenned){
      $('#layerslider_12 .ls-bottom-slidebuttons').children()[1].click();
      $('#layerslider_12 .ls-nav-stop').click();
    }else{
      $('#layerslider_12 .ls-bottom-slidebuttons').children()[0].click();
      setTimeout(()=>{$('#layerslider_12 .ls-nav-start').click();},1000)
    }
})
});
```

Comment: Thank youuuu it's perfect :o

Comment: @brandydoll np :)